# When is $R^n / ( I \cdot R^n) = (R/I)^n$, for ring $R$ and ideal $I$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am looking at a set of old lecture notes in which I scribbled: $R^n / ( I \cdot R^n) = (R/I)^n$. However, I cannot recall why this is true. The setting is that $R$ is commutative, has identity, and $I$ is a maximal ideal. Not all of these will be relevant here of course.

From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/882976/i-cdot-rn-i-for-ideal-i-in-commutative-ring-r-with-identity), I know that $I \cdot R^n = I$. And I also know that $I^n \subseteq I$ since its closed under right multiplication. Maybe if $I^n = I$, I can use $R^n/I^n$?

Is the claim correct and how do I complete the proof?

Comment: This is the direct sum of copies of $R$, not a product ideal.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the equation $I\cdot R^n=I$. The left-hand side I take it is the $R$-submodule $\{ix:i\in I,x\in R^n\}$, where $R$ acts on $R^n$ diagonally making it an $R$-module. On the other hand $I$ is a subset of $R$, not $R^n$. Even if you embed $I$ diagonally into $R^n$, this equality isn't true, since not everything in $I\cdot R^n$ has equal coordinates. (And my interpretation of $I\cdot R^n$ makes it an $R$-submodule of $R^n$ but not an $R^n$-submodule, i.e. not an ideal of $R^n$, so surely I don't understand what $I\cdot R^n$ is supposed to mean.)

Comment: @blue - YES. The solution here is that I misread my notes. Thanks! Will delete this question.

Comment: @egreg - Oops, I see now. I misread my notes. Will delete this question.

Comment: And $IR^n=I^n$ is almost obvious.

Comment: @egreg - $R^n$ as a direct product right? Yes its obvious if I understood the action correctly as $i \cdot (r_1,r_2) = (ir_1,ir_2)$ and since $I \cdot R = I$.

Comment: The set $IR^n$ (usually) is the set of sums of elements of the form $ax$, with $a\in I$ and $x\in R^n$. Since in $R^n$ you have the standard basis, it follows that $IR^n$ consists of $n$-tuples $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)$ such that $a_k\in I$, $k=1,2,\dots,n$. Just considering elements of the form $ax$ and not their sums, would not make $IR^n$ a submodule.

Comment: @egreg - i see. thanks a lot for sorting this out for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lecture notes are probably talking about direct sums. With $R^n$ the free module of rank $n$ is denoted, while, for an $R$-module $M$, $IM$ is the set of sums of the form
$$
\sum_{k=1}^m a_k x_k
$$
with $a_k\in I$ and $x_k\in M$ (and any natural $m$).

If $I$ is a left ideal of $R$ (commutativity is not relevant) and $M$ a left $R$-module, then $IM$ is a submodule of $M$.

In the case where $M=R^n$ it's almost clear that
$$
IR^n=\{(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n): a_k\in I, k=1,2,\dots,n\}=I^n
$$
because
$$
(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)=a_1e_1+a_2e_2+\dots+a_ne_n\in IR^n
$$
where $e_1,e_2,\dots,e_n$ are the elements of the standard basis. The reverse inclusion is easy.

Thus this boils down to proving that if $L_1$ is a submodule of $M_1$ a $L_2$ is a submodule of $M_2$, then
$$
\frac{M_1\oplus M_2}{L_1\oplus L_2}\cong \frac{M_1}{L_1}\oplus \frac{M_2}{L_2}
$$
which is just computations.

Comment: Thanks for writing this up! +1 and accepted. Yep, everything is completely right. I forgot what my badly scribbled notes were talking about.